# Distinguish operation in wso2

Tags: soap, wso2

I came from OpenESB (Glassfish) and I'm new with wso2. I have to mediate a service that it has two operations, 'Block' and 'Consult'. 
The only way to distinguish the operations is to evaluate the first node from the soap:body, throught a switch mediator, but always go by default, it doesn't work the case.
(I can't make the distinguish throught get-property('Action') because it doesn't come as http header).

My code to analize the soap-message is the above:

```
     `<log level="custom">
        <property xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"
                  name="OP"
                  expression="$body/*[1]"/>
     </log>
     <switch xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" source="$body/*[1]">
        <case regex=".*ConsultRequest.*">
           <log level="custom">
              <property name="OPERATION" value="CONSULT"/>
           </log>
        </case>
        <case regex=".*BlockRequest.*">
           <log level="custom">
              <property name="OPERATION" value="BLOCK"/>
           </log>
        </case>
        <default>
           <log level="custom">
              <property name="OPERATION" value="DEFAULT"/>
           </log>
        </default>
     </switch>`
```

and the result in the server console is next:

`[2015-04-15 11:15:04,611]  INFO - LogMediator OP = <cli:BlockRequest xmlns:cli="http://www.eroski.es/pspr/schema/ClientesMDM"><Id_Cliente_Hub>25</Id_Cliente_Hub></cli:BlockRequest>
[2015-04-15 11:15:04,611]  INFO - LogMediator OPERATION = DEFAULT`

¿Is there anyway to know what operation is invoked by some property?

Can anybody help me :(

Answer (score 0):

$body/*[1] is not the node name, but it's content (value or child xml tree). If you want to get it's name without namespace information, you can use a xpath function called **local-name** :

`local-name($body/*[1])`